# Calculating marginal distribution from Discrete Joint Probability Distribution

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, sensors

My question is related to multivariable joint distribution. I have one source variable "x" and multiple receivers "y1" "y2" "y3". I have each joint distribution p(x,y1),p(x,y2), p(x,y3). 
My question is how do I get p(x) from combination of the 3.
The issues in my mind are

If I calculate p(x) from p(x,y1). I already think that this should be exactly the p(x) obtained from other joint distributions. But in a real scenario, we have to estimate these distributions which would yield different marginal for p(x).

I do not have code yet but if someone can point out the direction then it would really be helpful

Comment: Interesting question, although since it's more conceptual, it's really more suited to stats.stackexchange.com. What do you mean, source and receiver variables? Can you say something about what x, y1, y2, and y3 actually are? Maybe you would be interested in concepts from Bayesian belief networks -- a web search for that term will find a lot of resources.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the right platform to ask. I will post the question in relevant forum. I am new to Bayesian networks and my question is regarding implementation of a simple sensor network. x is a transmitter that transmits bpsk symbol. y1 y2 and y3 are three sensors that receive same x and their distribution is to be calculated using training symbols. I hope it explains the questions and motive how to to obtain the marginal p_x given the joint statistics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on modeling sensors with belief networks in my dissertation. See: http://riso.sourceforge.net My dissertation is a little ways down on the page. A model for sensors which measure the same thing is described in Section 6.5.

In brief, when you have multiple measurements `y1, y2, y3` of the same thing `x`, you can model the joint probability of all of them as `p(x, y1, y2, y3) = p(y1 | x) p(y2 | x) p(y3 | x) p(x)`, where each `p(y | x)` is a measurement model, i.e., it represents the way that the measurement is a function of the thing being measured. Then the goal is to compute `p(x | y1, y2, y3)`. It turns out that's proportional to `p(y1 | x) p(y2 | x) p(y3 | x) p(x)`, with the constant of proportionality being whatever is needed to make the expression integrate to 1 over `x`. I.e., to combine information from multiple sensors, given this model, you multiply them together.

If you open a question on stats.stackexchange.com, I can say more about it. Hope this helps.